# Выделение определенной строки со словом C# RichTextBpx

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы текст, идущий после слова "Ответ:" (включительно) выделялся жирным. "Ответ" в тексте один и он всегда на последней строке.

Как будет вернее это сделать?

Пытался так, не получилось.

```
int index = 0, charIndex = 0, i = 0;
do
{
    index = richTextBox1.Find("Ответ:", index + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
    i++;
    if (index != -1) charIndex = i;
}
while ((index != -1));
int lineIndex = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
int startFromIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex);
int lineLength = richTextBox1.Lines[lineIndex].Length;
richTextBox1.Select(startFromIndex, lineLength);
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
```

Comment: А как уже пробовали?

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: в тексте много таких "ответов" или один? Чем разделены ответы и вопросы, если их много? лучше привести фрагмент текста для разбора

Comment: @rdorn Ответ один, он всегда на последней строке

Answer (score 1):

> Необходимо сделать так, чтобы текст, идущий после слова "Ответ:"
>   (включительно) выделялся жирным. Ответ один, он всегда на последней
>   строке

В этом случае все совсем просто. Я, откровенно говоря, не понял смысл вашей конструкции. То что "Ответ" всего один, сильно упрощает задачу, нам не требуется даже знать на какой именно строке он написан. У меня получилось так:

```
//тестировал на таком фрагменте.
richTextBox1.Text = "лорршгрртшщрн \r\nолпропор Ответ: \r\n  ншоргшргшршгргшршщг";
//ищем начало слова ответ 
int start = richTextBox1.Find("Ответ:");
//выделяем до конца текста
richTextBox1.Select(start, richTextBox1.Text.Length - start);
//в выделенный фрагмент устанавливаем шрифт, созданный из имеющегося, 
//но со стилем Bold - жирный
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
//сбрасываем выделение, тут в начало текста
richTextBox1.Select(0,0);
```

Вид текста после обработки:

> лорршгрртшщрн
>   олпропор **Ответ:
>
>     ншоргшргшршгргшршщг**

естественно, первый и последний пункты в коде нужно заменить на что-то более нужное и полезное.